# Perl script to convert xls to xlsx is generating blank xlsx and error message

Tags: excel, perl, xlsxwriter

executing the below perl script to convert xls to xlsx but it is generating the blank xlsx by giving the below error message. Please help me in correcting the code. Error message:

> Odd number of elements in hash assignment at
>   /usr/local/share/perl5/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm line 175.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $excel_xls = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel -> new ('Test.xls');
my ($sheet_xls, $row, $col, $cell);

my $excel_xlsx = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new('Test.xlsx');
my $sheet_xlsx = $excel_xlsx->add_worksheet();


for $sheet_xls ( @{ $excel_xls->{Worksheet} } ) {
    for $row ( $sheet_xls->{MinRow} .. $sheet_xls->{MaxRow} ) {
        for $col ( $sheet_xls->{MinCol} .. $sheet_xls->{MaxCol} ) {
            my $cell = $sheet_xls->{Cells}[$row][$col];
            print "$cell->{Val} ";
            $sheet_xlsx->write($row, $col, $cell->{Val});
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: When you need to update your question, do not do it in comments. Edit your original question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per user requirements the script is performing following operations.

1. writing CSV data to xlsx file
2. user needs to provide the input directory path (where multiple csv files are going to present)
3. user needs to provide the output directory (where xlsx files are going to be created)
4. script is performing following verification

   - if input directory not specified as command line argument, show error
   - if output directory is not specified as command line argument, show error
   - checking for directory exists
   - checking for csv file and also time tag information in the file name
   - only valid csv file is processed to create xlsx file.

> Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
# this module helps to read csv data from file
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
# this module helps to create xlsx file
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use File::Basename;

# get files from input directory
sub get_files {
    my $dir = shift // '.';
    my @all_files = ();
    opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Could not open '$dir' for reading '$!'\n";
    my @files = readdir $dh;
    foreach my $file (@files) {
        if ($file eq '.' or $file eq '..') {
            next;
        }
        # check for file .csv
        if ((( split /\./, $file )[-1]) eq "csv") {
            # winodws os syntax
            push @all_files, "$dir\\$file";
            # linux os syntax
            #push @all_files, "$dir/$file";
        }
    }
    closedir $dh;
    return @all_files;
}

# get digit from string
sub get_digit {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my ($digit) = $string =~ /(\d+)/;
    return ((defined $digit) ? $digit : '');
}

# write data to excel file
sub write_excel {
    my ($worksheet,$aoa) = @_;
    my $row = 0;
    foreach my $internal_array_ref (@$aoa) {
        my $col=0;
        foreach my $element (@$internal_array_ref) {
            # if element is not having any value
            $element = '' unless defined $element;
            $worksheet->write_string( $row, $col++, $element );
        }
        $row++;
    }
}

### Main ##
my $csv_dir;
my $output_dir;
# command line arguments
# input directory (--idir)which going to contain csv files
# ouput directory (--odir) where xlsx files going to be created
GetOptions(
    'idir=s' => \$csv_dir,
    'odir=s' => \$output_dir,
) or die "Usage: $0 --idir Directory PATH -odir DIRECTORY PATH \n";

# if input directory is not specified  as an input argument, show error
if (not defined $csv_dir) {
    print "\n Argument 'idir' is mandatory \n";
    print "for example $0 --ifile DIRPATH";
    exit 1;
}

# if output directory is not specified as an input argument, show error
if (not defined $output_dir) {
    print "\n Argument 'odir' is mandatory \n";
    print "for example $0 --odir DIRECTORY PATH";
    exit 1;
}

# check for input and output directory path
if ((-d $csv_dir) && (-d $output_dir)) {
    # get all csv files from input directory
    my @csv_files = get_files($csv_dir);
    # read csv file data and create xlsx file
    foreach my $csv_file (@csv_files) {
        # Check for file contain date digit
        my $date_digit = get_digit($csv_file);
        if ($date_digit eq '') {
            print "\n $csv_file not contain date information \n";
        } else {
            # excel file name with date digit
            # get file name from given file path (except extension)
            my $filename = basename("$csv_file",  ".csv");
            # this syntax is for windows to create xlsx file path
            my $excel_file = "$output_dir\\$filename.xlsx";
            # this syntax is for windows to create xlsx file path
            #my $excel_file = "$output_dir/$filename.xlsx";

            #  Read whole file in memory (as array of array)
            # change seperate char as per your csv file data
            # change quote char as per your csv file data (else just mentioned undef)
            # change escape char as per your csv file data (else just mentioned undef)
            eval {
                my $aoa = csv (in => $csv_file,     
                        encoding => "UTF-8",
                        sep_char    => ',',
                        quote_char  => '"',
                        escape_char => undef);

                if (scalar @$aoa) {
                    # Create a new Excel workbook
                    my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $excel_file );
                    # Add a worksheet
                    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
                    # write csv data to excel file
                    write_excel($worksheet,$aoa);
                    $workbook->close();
                    print "\n The $excel_file created sucessfully. \n";
                }
            };

            if ($@) {
                print "\n Invalid CSV file or check CSV file format \n";
            }
        }
    }
}  else {
    print "\n Please provide valid directiory path: $csv_dir or Please provide valid directory path $output_dir";
    exit 1;
}
```

> Output and execution syntax

```
### Windows
C:\Users\batman\source\repos>perl csv_xlsx.pl --idir C:\Users\batman\source\repos\csv --odir C:\Users\batman\source\repos\excel_out

 The C:\Users\batman\source\repos\excel_out\sample_dept1_20200609.xlsx created sucessfully.

 The C:\Users\batman\source\repos\excel_out\sample_dept2_20200610.xlsx created sucessfully.

### Linux
perl csv_xlsx.pl --idir /Users/batman/source/repos/csv --odir /Users/batman/source/repos/excel_out
```

Comment: Amit, It is working very much fine. Thanks a lot for your help. Will get back to you with one more question with another requirement. Till then, Thank you again..!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this forum is for fixing code issue (not for writing code). Please share question with code on stackoverflow page.  Many freelance developer portals are available these developer will write code as per your requirement

Comment: Thanks, Amit. One last question. How to handle the same code for multiple files in one go. I have input files like: sample_dept1_$currdate.csv, sample_dept2_$currdate.csv, sample_dept3_$currdate.csv and need to convert into xlsx like(sample_dept1_$currdate.xlsx, sample_dept2_$currdate.xlsx, sample_dept3_$currdate.xlsx)in one go. Appreciate your help. Also, please let me know the freelance developer portals info. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Amit..requirement is same, only difference is, multiple files and only dept number changes in the files names. like, sample_dept1_$currdate.csv, sample_dept2_$currdate.csv, sample_dept3_$currdate.csv. All will be in the same folder like the previous code. Need to convert them into xlsx in one shot. Thank you..!!

Comment: How many times are you going to answer this question? None of your answers have any explanation or rationale. Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. When you answer, explain what you did, why you did it, and how that avoids the questioner's confusion.

Comment: True, I also said user to upload code "Thanks for your reply. But this forum is for fixing code issue (not for writing code). Please share question with code on stackoverflow page. Many freelance developer portals are available these developer will write code as per your requirement "

Comment: @vijayasekharchengalrayappa can you please post question with code on stackoverflow page?

Comment: sure..I will post a question..Thanks

Comment: @briandfoy I have explained vijayashkar, can you please remove downvote (humble request)

Comment: Explain what your program does and how it solves the problem, and consolidate all of your answers into one answer. As it is now, your answer is of no use to anyone else.

Comment: @briandfoy , as per your suggestion I have added necessary information in above post and deleted all other posts. Please check and let me know if any changes required

Comment: @vijayasekharchengalrayappa I have deleted old posts. this post is the final one (please check) with all code. If you want to upvote then provide upvote to this post.

Comment: @briandfoy can you please remove downvote if no changes are required.

Comment: You haven't answered his question about the "odd number of  elements". Remember, StackOverflow is only marginally for the person asking the question. Simply listing the steps steps your program doesn't add that much.

Comment: Amit, I didn't devote at all. Infact, your answers were very helpful and I'm grateful to you.

Comment: One last question, is there any way to make the xlsx READ only ( after converting csv to xlsx ) so that others can't change the data in it?

Comment: after print statement excel file created successfully  message add these line                                                         
`my $mode = 0444;   chmod $mode, "$excel_file"; `                                                       I lost all my points :(  no rewards for good work

Comment: @briandfoy regarding odd number of elements  Dave Cross provided the explanation and i have upvoted it. After that vijayasekhar provided another requirements I have helped him that's why i have mentioned steps what script is doing. I understood your point and  I will follow as guideline for my next answer but please remove downvote it's not motivating (humble request)

Comment: Thanks, Amit and I'm sorry for loosing points and that is not fair.                                      Hi Brian, my sincere request is tp upvote it as Amit was very helpful. I will make sure that the mess will not happen in future..Thank you..!!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should take a slightly closer look at the [documentation for the `new()` method in Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/DOUGW/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.65/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm#new()). The examples look like this:

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();

$parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new( Password => 'secret' );

$parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new(
    CellHandler => \&cell_handler,
    NotSetCell  => 1,
);
```

The method requires either no parameters or a list of key/value pairs. Your call to that method looks like this:

```
my $excel_xls = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel -> new ('Test.xls');
```

There is no example that takes a filename as a parameter. Parsing a file is a two-stage process. You create a parser object:

```
my $parser = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
```

And then you use the `parse()` method on that object to parse a spreadsheet:

```
my $excel_xls = $parser->parse('Test.xls');
```

If you're only parsing a single file, then you can combine these two lines into one:

```
my $excel_xls = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new()->parse('Test.xls');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your new requirement ( pass parameter file path to program) i have added necessary code. Install (Getopt::Long perl module)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Getopt::Long;
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

# get digit from string
sub get_digit {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my ($digit) = $string =~ /(\d+)/;
    return ((defined $digit) ? $digit : '');
}

# write data to excel file
sub write_excel {
    my ($worksheet,$aoa) = @_;
    my $row = 0;
    foreach my $internal_array_ref (@$aoa) {
        my $col=0;
        foreach my $element (@$internal_array_ref) {
            # if element is not having any value
            $element = '' unless defined $element;
            $worksheet->write( $row, $col++, $element );
        }
        $row++;
    }
}

### Main ##
my $csv_file;
my $excel_file;
GetOptions('file=s' => \$csv_file) or die "Usage: $0 --file FILENAME\n";
if (not defined $csv_file) {
    print "\n Argument 'file' is mandatory \n";
    print "for example $0 --file FILEPATH";
    exit 1;
}
# check for file exists and not empty
if (-s $csv_file) {
    # Check for file contain date digit
    my $date_digit = get_digit($csv_file);
    if ($date_digit eq '') {
        print "\n $csv_file not contain date information \n";
        exit 1;
    } else {
        # excel file name with date digit
        $excel_file = "csv_to_excel_$date_digit.xlsx";
        #  Read whole file in memory (as array of array)
        # change seperate char as per your csv file data
        # change quote char as per your csv file data (else just mentioned undef)
        # change escape char as per your csv file data (else just mentioned undef)
        eval {
            my $aoa = csv (in => $csv_file,     
                        encoding => "UTF-8",
                        sep_char    => ',',
                        quote_char  => '"',
                        escape_char => undef);

            if (scalar @$aoa) {
                # Create a new Excel workbook
                my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( $excel_file );
                # Add a worksheet
                my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
                # write to excel file
                write_excel($worksheet,$aoa);
                $workbook->close();
                print "\n The $excel_file created sucessfully. \n";
            }
        };

        if ($@) {
            print "\n Invalid CSV file or check CSV file format \n";
            exit 1;
        }
    }
}  else {
    print "\n Please provide valid file path: $csv_file";
    exit 1;
}
```

> output

```
perl csv_xlsx.pl

 Argument 'file' is mandatory
for example csv_xlsx.pl --file FILEPATH
##############
perl csv_xlsx.pl --file
Option file requires an argument
Usage: csv_xlsx.pl --file FILENAME
#############
perl csv_xlsx.pl --file sample.csv

 sample.csv not contain date information
###############
perl csv_xlsx.pl --file sample_20200609.csv

 The csv_to_excel_20200609.xlsx created sucessfully
```

Comment: sample_$currentdate.csv and sample_$currentdate.xlsx. Both will be in the same folder == > you can just change file name (path in above code)

Comment: If you have confusion regarding dealing with file path. Let me know path I will add directory path in above code

Comment: Need to add file path as the parameter. Also,let's not hard code the output file also within the script. we will have the $excel_file = "sample_$date_digit.xlsx". Because same perl script, I will have to use for different csv files across the application. thanks

Comment: this is example .. hardcoding file path is bad programming.. you can pass  output directory path as command line argument.

Comment: yes, please...please add  input as well as output directory path as command line argument

Comment: Can you please try to add this requirement.. very interesting .. good learning for you.. (just need to modify above code hint add one more command line parameter for output) then share your code.. I will help to improve your code.